Expression function
I want to add a new line after ratio "Intercellular/ambient CO2" and C[i]/C[a] should come in second line using expression() function any suggestions i am using following code
expression(bold(Intercellualr/ambient~CO[2]~ratio \n (C[i]/C[a])))


Use atop like this:
hdg <- ~ bold(atop(Intercellualr/ambient~CO[2]~ratio, C[i]/C[a]))
plot(0, main = hdg)


